# How to get the MD5Sum of a DEB file

Tags: ubuntu, md5, deb

My question is how do I get the MD5Sum of a DEB file? I'm making a cydia repo, and my Packages file needs this. I know how to find an MD5Sum, I just don't know what to convert to MD5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
md5sum package.deb
```

... Assuming this is the file containing your package.

Seriously, though, the toolchain already knows how to calculate this. Just use the existing Debian tools to set up your repo.

Comment: Thanks! At the time, I was using a Mac, and thought I could do it manually. I couldn't get MacPorts, because it was PPC.

Comment: The Mac comes with a command `md5` which produces slightly different output.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the .deb file using the ar tool; extract the control.tar.gz file in it. Check if the contrl.tar has a file md5sums. cat md5sums. This will print the filenames to the right side and their md5 sums to the left. You are most probably looking for these files.